# EF simple 1-* relationship results in a strange SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to debug an EF 6.1.1 generated SQL query and I've been able to reproduce the problem with this small amount of coude. It is a simple one-to-many unidirectional relationship that I'm trying to eager-load:

The model is as follows:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Recipient> RecipientHistory { get; set; }
    public IList<Payer> PayerHistory { get; set; }
}

public class Recipient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Payer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the EF mapping classes:

```
public class SubscriptionMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subscription>
{
    public SubscriptionMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Subscriptions");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("subscription_id");

        HasMany(p => p.RecipientHistory)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("subscription_id"));

        HasMany(p => p.PayerHistory)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("subscription_id"));
    }
}

public class RecipientMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Recipient>
{
    public RecipientMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Subscription_recipients");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("subscription_recipient_id");
    }
}

public class PayerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Payer>
{
    public PayerMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Subscription_payers");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("subscription_payer_id");
    }
}
```

When I'm executing the following query against the store:

```
db.Set<Subscription>()
    .Include(s => s.RecipientHistory)
    .Include(s => s.PayerHistory)
    .ToList();
```

The resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[subscription_id] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[subscription_recipient_id] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll1].[subscription_id1] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C9]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[subscription_recipient_id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        1 AS [C2], 
        [Extent1].[subscription_id] AS [subscription_id], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[subscription_recipient_id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C3], 
        [Extent2].[subscription_recipient_id] AS [subscription_recipient_id], 
        [Extent2].[subscription_id] AS [subscription_id1], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier) AS [C6]
        FROM  [dbo].[Subscriptions] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Subscription_recipients] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[subscription_id] = [Extent2].[subscription_id]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        2 AS [C2], 
        [Extent3].[subscription_id] AS [subscription_id], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier) AS [C5], 
        2 AS [C6], 
        [Extent4].[subscription_payer_id] AS [subscription_payer_id], 
        [Extent4].[subscription_id] AS [subscription_id1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Subscriptions] AS [Extent3]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subscription_payers] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[subscription_id] = [Extent4].[subscription_id]) AS [UnionAll1]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[subscription_id] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

And that seems pretty unnecessary to me for such a simple query. Am I missing something in my mappings, or is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading two different dependencies is rather tricky. This is a safe way to do just that, while using as little space as possible - note that the results are `null` for all the rows that *aren't* the "included" part.

The basic problem is that with two 1:* associations, you'd have trouble separating the included entities that are from the first association from those of the second. The same problem doesn't appear when you're dealing with 1:(0-)1, because the result will simply be a single record.

The thing is, you're thinking of this as "a simple 1 to many relationship". If you've ever tried to write  a similar query in SQL, you must know that 1:* is actually quite complex to work with, especially if you need to combine many different 1:*s in one query. Now, there's alternatives (for example, using a `xml` field in the result set), but this is probably the one that lets the server do as many optimizations as it can, and the overhead would actually be rather small in practice - again, note that you're only getting each piece of data once - the rest is `null`s - that's why the first query does a `left join` (it has to return the parent even if there's nothing in the relation), while the second is free to do an `inner join` (and doesn't have to select any columns from the parent except for the primary key). This could still be improved if there was a way not to return the parent's data in each row of the first sub-query, but that's easier said than done (and will probably end up being much slower).

All in all, this is a bit eloquent query, but it does what it has to do. Are you having performance problems, or are you just curious?

Comment: Thank you very much Luaan. Your explanation is very helpful, and I see the problems with more than one 1:* in a single query now. I was just curious - no performance problems. I just got a bit worried at the moment, thinking that the query seemed overly compelx for what it had to do. But it makes perfectly sense now.